# Visualizing Turtlebot Kinect Data - Empty menu on New Display window

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New turtlebot user. I was able to teleoperate turtlebot.
Now I am following "Visualizing Turtlebot Kinect Data" tutorial.
When I click the Add button on RViz window, New Display window opens, but there is nothing listed to add.
Do I need to install anything special before running RViz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32692/visualizing-turtlebot-kinect-data---empty-menu-on-new-display-window/) by [Ozkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2258/ozkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-04-26**:
Can you post the output of running "rostopic list" on the computer you're using rviz on? Also, when you have new information about your problem, please edit your question rather than posting an answer.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-04-26**:
Can you post the output of running "rostopic list" on the computer you're using rviz on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your rviz config was cleared you may not be loading the default plugins.  See the [rviz User Manual](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide#Plugins) for instructions.

You need to make sure the "Builtin" plugins are checked off as "Loaded".

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ozkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2258/ozkan/) on 2012-05-07**:
Plugins were not checked. Now that I checked it, the list is visible now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nope, that link doesn't help. I couldn't get there.
I cannot add a Camera or PointCloud2 since nothing is listed at the New Display window.

If you can open the following image from the RViz user guide:
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/attachments/rviz(2f)UserGuide/new_display_dialog.png
In my case, there are no options listed.

---

Originally posted by [Ozkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2258/ozkan/) with karma: 38 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1